# Refining server/client TCP socket example

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I have an example of server code for server/client communication through wifi.
Problem is that as soon as client app is restarted or WIFI signal is lost server app closes.

1. How to keep server app working and maintain ability for new connections?
2. How to  keep Server app "alive" when wifi signal is lost?

**code**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

Handler updateConversationHandler;

Thread serverThread = null;

private TextView text;

public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

    this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.serverThread.start();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {
                String read = input.readLine();
                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {

    private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public  void run() {

        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg + "<br>" + text.getText()));


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the IOException. For example, when the WiFi signal is lost, find where the exception is returned, and handle that exception (instead of just printing the stack trace).